# How to get data collected from url in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

Im trying to use the if statement in blade template to show and hide section based on tab clicked. If I do `['no' =>'1']`, I get `$name = 1`. but if I do
`['no' =>'{{no}}']`, it return nothing.How should I write to get `$name = 1` with `['no' =>'{{no}}']`?

---

web.php

```
Route::get('/welcome/{no}', function () {
    return view('welcome',['no' =>'{{no}}']);
});
```

---

welcome.blade.php

```
@if ($no == 1)
    @include('post.article')
@else
    @include('post.event')
@endif
```

Comment: If you check the [manual about route parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-parameters), you can see that you need to add them as arguments to your controller function: `Route::get('/foo/{bar}', function($bar) { ... });` and then pass the `$bar` variable to the view.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the description. I understand it now and it does work.

Answer (score 1):

You should give like this in your Route:

```
Route::get('/welcome/{no}', function ($no) {
    return view('master/accesslog',['no' =>$no]);
});
```

This will be considered as string `'{{no}}'`

Comment: Understand. if not define `function($no)` , the `['no' => $no]` will return `$no` as undefine var.